# How to link files in VSCode IDE

Tags: g++

I am new to c++ programming, I have 1 .obj and 2 header files and don't know how to link them to main.CPP. can anyone help me??

P.S. I am using Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2):

a friendly advise:

Programming is such a profession that requires you to do a bit of reading and reflecting.

Buy the first book on c++ in the book store, read up a little bit and decide early on, if this is for you or not.